# Physical description of spin wave theory and Bogoliubov transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

I am trying to understand how spin-wave theory explain the behaviour of a spin-wave in a spin system. To clarify my question, I will start with a simple case of a antiferromagnet (AFM). The Hamiltonian is given as:
$$H = J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}\vec{S}_i\cdot \vec{S}_{j}$$
where $\langle i,j\rangle$ denoted sum is on nearest neighbors (NN) only. We assume that we have two sublattices denoted by $A$ and $B$ with index $i$ and $j$, respectively. The spin-wave theory can be applied in three steps:

1. apply Holstein-Primikoff transformation (HPT): it basically says that the small deviation (precession motion) of $\vec{S}_i$ is created (destroyed) by operator $a_i^+(a_i)$ on lattice $A$ and $b_j^+(b_j)$ on lattice $B$:
   $$H= -\frac{NzJS^2}{2}+H_1$$
   where
   $$H_1 = zJS\sum_{i\epsilon A} a_i^+a_i + zJS\sum_{j\epsilon B} b_j^+b_j + JS\sum_{\langle i,j \rangle} (a_ib_{j}+a_{i}^+b_j^+)$$
   and we ignore higher-order interaction.
2. apply the Fourier transform:
   $$H_1 = zJS\sum_k [\gamma_k^* a_kb_{-k} + \gamma_k a_k^+b_{-k}^+ + a_k^+a_k + b_{-k}^+b_{-k}]$$
   where $\gamma_k =1/z\sum_\delta e^{ik\cdot \delta}$. And $z$ is number of NN and $\delta$ is location of NN.
3. to diagonalize apply Bogoliubov transformation
   $$\alpha_k = u_k a_k - v_k b_{-k}^+ \quad ; \quad \beta_k^+ = -v_k a_k + u_k b_{-k}^+$$
   this gives us the following results
   $$H_1 = \sum_k \epsilon_k (\alpha_k^+ \alpha_k + \beta_k^+ \beta_k)$$
   where $\epsilon_k = zJS\sum_k \sqrt{1-\gamma_k^2}$

**My question:**

Till 2nd step, I know what's going on. But I am confused about what exactly happen in 3rd step. We now have new operators. How these new operators ($\alpha, \beta$) describe a spin-wave?

Does the last equation mean that a spin-wave of energy $\epsilon_k$ can exist in this AFM? And there can be only one spin-wave (two-fold degenerate) of this energy?